# Google docs не видит разметку Open Graph

Tags: html, opengraph

Пытаюсь настроить url preview, все сервисы типа facebook, Vk, Telegram видят и рисуют нормальное превью, кроме google таблицы и документы. Почему это может происходить, ниже напишу head, не подхватывает ни картинку, ни описание или оглавление

```
<!--  Google meta  -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mooncnsrd.ru/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Mooncnrd" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Мой профессиональный сайт" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/static/link-cover.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="preview" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="/static/link-cover.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="940" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="/static/link-cover.jpg" />
<!--  Twitter meta  -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Mooncnrd" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Мой профессиональный сайт" />
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="/static/link-cover.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

У `<meta>` нет аттрибута `property`. Как минимум. Может быть, перепутали с `name`?

Comment: Любой элемент может иметь атрибут property, просто это прописано в другой спецификации https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/

Comment: Так прописываются мета теги для превью